# Why isnt the array adding the character's in the below program?

Tags: java, return

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CharacterList {

    private char [] charArray;
    private int count;

    public CharacterList(int arraySize){

        charArray = new char[arraySize];

        for(int i = 0; i<charArray.length; i++){
            charArray[i] = ' ';
        }

        count = 0;

    }

    public int indexOf(char searchingChar) {

        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {

            if(charArray[i] == searchingChar){
                return i;
            }

        }
        return -1;

    }


    public boolean addCharacter(char characterToAdd){

        if(indexOf(characterToAdd) == -1 && charArray[charArray.length-1] != ' '){

            doubleArrayCapacity();
            for(int i = 0; i<charArray.length; i++){

                if(charArray[i] == ' '){

                    charArray[i] = characterToAdd;
                }
            }
            count ++;
            return true;

        } else if(indexOf(characterToAdd) == -1){

            for(int i = 0; i<charArray.length; i++){

                if(charArray[i] == ' '){

                    charArray[i] = characterToAdd;
                }
            }
            count++;
            return true;

        } else
            return false;

    }

    public String toString(){

        return Arrays.toString(charArray);
    }


}
```

```
output:
Entered command: 1
a was added
Entered command: 1
b was added
Entered command: 1
c was added
Entered command: 1
d was added
Entered command: 3
[a, a,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
```

The above code is one class. (The other class is not given for readability purposes). I tried inputting a,b,c (I wanted to add these elements in the array). However, the above output occurs. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is your _expected_ output?

Comment: Could you add the implementation of `doubleArrayCapacity()`?

Comment: @Kacper private void doubleArrayCapacity() {
        char [] newCharArray = new char[this.charArray.length*2];
        for(int i=0; i<this.charArray.length-1; i++) {
            newCharArray[i] = this.charArray[i];
        }
        this.charArray = newCharArray;
    }

Comment: Could you edit you question and add it to it?

Comment: @Kacper I tried. The system is not allowing me because there's too much code. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @dnault I would like the output to be [a, b, c, d]

Answer (score 0):

a) The for where you add the character, you don't stop until you fill all the array with the character from the first point where there is ' '.
means, when you inserted 'a' the array saw 'a' wasn't showing so and all the array is empty so the 'a' was inserted to the first place and the i = i+1 and also there the place was empty so the 'a' was inserted to second place. the array supposed to get full so and I am not sure why it inserted only two a's but send you main code plz.
b) why do you use count? I saw you only updating it without using it...